# Rollback the changes in failure situation

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a situation where we update an entity data and then based on certain type of updates we may update another entity as well.

There are situations when the updation in the second entry may fail for some reasons and throw exceptions.

The question is how to handle this situation as we would like to rollback the changes done in the first entity.

We cannot defer the update to the first entry until the second entry update.

In the current situation if that happens then

as soon as the code reach the below block then it will commit the first entry changes even there are failures in 2nd entity update. so how to rollback? I think not closing the persistentManager if 2nd entity update is failed is not the right option.

```
finally {
            try {
                if (pm != null && pm.isClosed() == false )
                    pm.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.severe("Exception in finally of execute of updateDonor");
                log.severe("Exception class is :" + e.getClass().getName());
                log.severe("Exception is :" + e.getMessage());
                throw new Exception(e.getMessage()
                        + "Unable to close persistence manager");
            }
            log.info("end of updateDonor");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your situation, but would [cross-group](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview#Cross_Group_Transactions) (XG) transactions, which allow a transaction to be applied to entities from more than one entity group, be what you are looking for?  Search for 'cross-group transactions on [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Using_Transactions) as well. With an XG transaction, either all changes to the entities encompassed by the transaction go through, or none do.

Comment: Well we are using jdo so looks like we need to enable in the jdoconfig.xml for all the entities to be able to run cross group transactions. However, I do not see the code on the page for jdo case? I mean how to start a txn and finish it? Just to clear my requirements we want to run atomic update to two different entities.